# How do I inform the user every time there is change in status

Tags: notification, alerts

I'm currently designing a monitoring tool for vehicle parking lot - where I have to inform users every time a car parked and left. User doesn't have to acknowledge the notifications. It is just an alert to user to inform the change. I expect a lot of notifications for the same. How do I design these to make it less annoying for user?

Suppose there are n lanes and whenever a car goes to a lane I need to tell the user that one of the lane has a car. This updates are shown as status such as normal for 1 car waiting, crowded for 10 cars waiting. I need a way to let the user know the status change i.e. normal to crowded and vice versa. One way I can think of is to notify the user but that way I'll be spamming him every time there is a change.

Comment: Could you pl. elaborate more, it's too broad to help you with what you want.

Comment: Suppose there are n lanes and when ever a car goes to a lane i need to tell the user that one of the lane has a car. This updates are shown as status such as regular(1 car), crowded(10 cars waiting). I need a way to let the user know the status change i.e regular to crowded and vice versa. One way I can think of is to notify the user but that way ill be spamming him every time there is a change.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of presenting the user with notification, you could update the home segment of the tool dashboard with real-time color coded information of the lanes, the way google maps does with street traffic. For example, at any instant,

Lane A- 5 cars in queue- Moderately crowded- Color code: Yellow
Lane B- 10 cars in queue- Heavily crowded- Color code: Red
Lane C- 1 car in queue- Regular traffic- Color code: Green

Since your tool is a parking monitoring tool, I suppose, this would be a primary use case. Sending notifications to the user for every change in queue would only spam the notification pane and would be hardly of any help to the user.

Instead, if you inform the user with real-time traffic information on each lane with color codes, the user would instantly understand the significance of the color code and would make a preference driven choice accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement based scenario. Your users would want to know if there is a parking space available only when they want to park their car.

Instead of sending notifications every time a change happens in parking lot, have a button in your app that says **Show Parking Space Availability**, when user taps on it you can show the status of that moment. It can be Normal or Crowded.

**Let the user ask you if there is a space available instead of you telling them when they may not need it.**